# Implementing caching technique in closest pair algorithm

Tags: c, caching, blocking, nonblocking

I am trying to optimize the [**closest pair brute force algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) and compare it with the non cached program but I am stuck.

The main problem, is that I get worse performance when I cache the calculations with the for loops its almost `cached time = 2 x non-cached time`. Its like nothing happens if i change the size of the block... I use a struct point array P for x,y cordinates

Here is the non-cached code:

```
void compare_points_BF(int *N, point *P){
    int i, j, p1, p2;
    float dx, dy, distance=0, min_dist=inf();
    long calc = 0;

    for (i=0; i<(*N-1) ; i++){
        for (j=i+1; j<*N; j++){
            dx = P[i].x - P[j].x;
            dy = P[i].y - P[j].y;
            //calculate distance of current points
            distance = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
            calc++;
            if (distance < min_dist){
                min_dist = distance;
                p1 = i;
                p2 = j;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%ld calculations\t", calc);
}
```

And here is the cached version:

```
    void compare_points_BF(int *N, int *B, point *P){
        int i, j, ib, jb, p1, p2, num_blocks = (*N + (*B-1)) / (*B);
        float dist=0, min_dist=inf();
        long calc=0;
    
        //break array data in N/B blocks
        for (i = 0; i < num_blocks; i++){
            for (j = i; j < num_blocks; j++){
                for (jb = j * (*B); jb < min((j+1) * (*B), *N); jb++){
                    //avoid double comparisons that occur when i block = j block
                    for (i == j ? (ib = jb + 1) : (ib = i*(*B)); ib < min((i+1) * (*B), *N); ib++){
                        calc++;
                        //calculate distance of current points
                        if((dist = (P[ib].x - P[jb].x) * (P[ib].x - P[jb].x) +
                                (P[ib].y - P[jb].y) * (P[ib].y - P[jb].y)) < min_dist){
                            min_dist = dist;
                            p1 = ib;
                            p2 = jb;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%ld calculations\t", calc);
}
```

For example the output of non-cached program is:

```
N = 8192     Run time: 0,080 sec
N = 16384    Run time: 0,330 sec
N = 32768    Run time: 1,280 sec
N = 65.536   Run time: 5,290 sec
N = 131.072  Run time: 21,290sec
N = 262.144  Run time: 81,880sec
N = 524.288  Run time: 327,460 sec
```

But with the cached example I get:

```
33550336 calculations   Block_size = 128    N = 8192    Run time: 0.402 sec
33550336 calculations   Block_size = 256    N = 8192    Run time: 0.383 sec
33550336 calculations   Block_size = 512    N = 8192    Run time: 0.384 sec
33550336 calculations   Block_size = 1024   N = 8192    Run time: 0.381 sec
33550336 calculations   Block_size = 2048   N = 8192    Run time: 0.398 sec
33550336 calculations   Block_size = 4096   N = 8192    Run time: 0.400 sec
33550336 calculations   Block_size = 8192   N = 8192    Run time: 0.401 sec
33550336 calculations   Block_size = 16384  N = 8192    Run time: 0.383 sec

134209536 calculations  Block_size = 128    N = 16384   Run time: 1.579 sec
134209536 calculations  Block_size = 256    N = 16384   Run time: 1.610 sec
134209536 calculations  Block_size = 512    N = 16384   Run time: 1.630 sec
134209536 calculations  Block_size = 1024   N = 16384   Run time: 1.530 sec
134209536 calculations  Block_size = 2048   N = 16384   Run time: 1.537 sec
134209536 calculations  Block_size = 4096   N = 16384   Run time: 1.562 sec
134209536 calculations  Block_size = 8192   N = 16384   Run time: 1.520 sec
134209536 calculations  Block_size = 16384  N = 16384   Run time: 1.626 sec

536854528 calculations  Block_size = 128    N = 32768   Run time: 6.170 sec
536854528 calculations  Block_size = 256    N = 32768   Run time: 6.207 sec
536854528 calculations  Block_size = 512    N = 32768   Run time: 6.219 sec
536854528 calculations  Block_size = 1024   N = 32768   Run time: 6.131 sec
536854528 calculations  Block_size = 2048   N = 32768   Run time: 6.077 sec
536854528 calculations  Block_size = 4096   N = 32768   Run time: 6.216 sec
536854528 calculations  Block_size = 8192   N = 32768   Run time: 6.130 sec
536854528 calculations  Block_size = 16384  N = 32768   Run time: 6.181 sec
```

I have checked over and over the code and it seems to be correct. What am I missing here?
Does the compiler optimize the code to implement better cache usage than what I am trying to achieve?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Four nested loops versus two, and seems to be more expressions to evaluate as well in your "cached" version. No that won't be faster.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But how am i supposed to break data in blocks without using extra for loops? Though, calculations are the same.

Comment: You only count the number of nested loops as your "calculations", but in your "cached" version there are many more expressions. Your "uncached" version is simple, simple is often good. And even if you could manage to squeeze one or two percent better run-time, it's often by making algorithms more complex and therefore much _much_ harder to understand.

Comment: What are you really trying too solve? Is it how to optimize a N squared algorithm  for closest pair?  It's just an assumption on your part that caching will speed up the implementation, have you considered other techniques, like loop unrolling or running on a GPU?

Comment: @TimChild I am just trying to understand how caching in cpu works. Thats why I picked a simple algorithm like Closest pair. So in other words, this simple algorithm cannot be boosted with a little cache tweaking ? Any suggestions for the code?

Comment: With the simple variant, the compiler (if optimising properly) stores `P[i].x` and `P[i].y` in registers, and then blasts through the remainder of the array sequentially - that is, if you change the function to return `min_dist`, or print out the indices `p1, p2`, otherwise, it just counts iterations - that is a really good access pattern and hard to beat.

Comment: @DanielFischer return or print => you are referring to the "cached" code right?

Comment: No, the simple code. As is, the only thing that survived the compilation was the loop control and `calc++;` plus the final print. I'd guess it'd be the same for the "cached" code, but I didn't check.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well I have checked both (returning and printing) but I dont get any performance improvement. Its the same and I cannot explain it.

Comment: You shouldn't get an improvement. The point is that without using the distance computations, the compiler eliminates them, and all you're left with is the loop control + the `calc++`, so you're not measuring any effect of cache locality.

Comment: @DanielFischer Now I see the reason, but apart from this how can I get this simple algorithm to work with "caching" technique? Is it feasible? Any code modifications that might do the trick?

Comment: I don't know if you can even beat the simple code for this. As I said above, that has a very good access pattern. _If_ you can beat it, you need simpler code on the block-wise thing. Treat the case of two points in the same block first, then loop over the remaining blocks.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well this is supposed to be beneficial for large number of data. Still, as you point out its kinda weird. The code I have posted is not the only one I have tried. I treated same block comparison with if else statement but the timings were exactly the same and so I preferred this one which is more compact. Simpler code, cant imagine anything more simple. I also tried without `j` index but still the same. Maybe caching works for more complex algorithms like matrix multiplication using optimized algorithms only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a long time but just to answer-close the question.

```
float compare_points_BF(register int N, register int B, point *P, register point *p1, *p2;){

register int i, j, ib, jb, iin, jjn, num_blocks = (N + (B-1)) / B;
register float distance=0, min_dist=FLT_MAX, regx, regy;

    //break array data in N/B blocks
    for (i = 0; i < num_blocks; i++){
        for (j = i; j < num_blocks; j++){
          iin = ( ((i+1)*B) < N ? ((i+1)*B) : N);
          jjn = (((j+1)*B) < N ? ((j+1)*B) : N);
          //reads the moving frame block to compare with the i block
          for (jb = j * B; jb < jjn; jb++){
            //avoid float comparisons that occur when i block = j block
            //Registers Allocated
            regx = P[jb].x;
            regy = P[jb].y;
            for (i==j ? (ib=jb+1):(ib=i*B); ib < iin; ib++){
               //calculate distance of current points
               if((distance = (P[ib].x - regx) * (P[ib].x - regx) +
                        (P[ib].y - regy) * (P[ib].y - regy)) < min_dist){
                min_dist = distance;
                p1 = &P[ib];
                p2 = &P[jb];
               }
             }
           }
         }
    }
    return sqrt(min_dist);
}
```

This use of cache can speed up to **10%**.
Here are some results.

```
Block
Size    Number of elements
        8192    16384   32768   65536   131072  262144  524288  1048576
128     0,079   0,310   1,260   4,960   19,740  78,990  315,661 1.260,862
256     0,079   0,310   1,250   4,940   19,830  78,820  315,410 1.258,402
512     0,080   0,320   1,260   4,920   19,640  78,480  313,851 1.253,141
1024    0,080   0,320   1,250   4,870   19,430  77,540  310,120 1.237,772
2048    0,079   0,310   1,240   4,850   19,340  77,061  308,211 1.229,892
4096    0,079   0,300   1,210   4,890   19,670  78,300  313,310 1.250,572
8192    0,078   0,310   1,210   4,870   19,510  78,110  312,770 1.249,091
16384           0,300   1,200   4,860   19,420  77,870  312,151 1.246,192
32768                   1,190   4,780   19,310  77,460  310,970 1.242,102
65536                           4,760   19,230  77,660  312,191 1.249,872
131072                                  18,972  76,850  310,470 1.246,261
262144                                          76,400  307,521 1.239,402
```